# Thinking of Minkowski addition as a disjoint union

Tags: general-topology

Given sets $A,B$ we define the Minkowski addition by $A\oplus B = \{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$. I think the idea is to think that at each point of $A$ we have a copy of $B$? At least that's how it seems to have been used in certain contexts.

My question is could you think of $A\oplus B = \sqcup_{a\in A} B$? I think at least the original definition is homeomorphic to my way of thinking?

Comment: The way you define it, it's just another new set created from $A$ and $B$ in a group with addition. Never heard of  Minkowski-addition. Wikipedia confirms it's just the addtion of sets to form a new set.

Comment: No, if $A=B=\{0,1\}$, then $A\oplus B=\{0,1,2\}$, but the disjoint union of $\lvert A\rvert$ copies of $B$ has $4$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the set addition $A + B = \{a+b: a \in A, b \in B\}$ is just a way to form a new set based on two sets. E.g. $A + \{0\} = A$, $[0,1] + [0,1] = [0,2]$ in the reals etc.

Don't mistake it for a disjoint union, but we can write

$$A + B = \cup_{a \in A}( \{a\} + B)$$

where $\{a\} + B$ is often denoted $a+B$ for short. All sets $a+B$ are homeomorphic to $B$ (As translation is a homeomorphism), but the union is in general far from disjoint:

E.g in $0 +[0,1]$ contains $\frac{1}{2}  =0 + \frac{1}{2}$ but so does $\frac{1}{2} + [0,1]$, as $\frac{1}{2} + 0$. and $[0,2]= [0,1] + [0,1]$ is not a disjoint union of copies of $[0,1]$ by connectedness arguments.

But the first equation does show that $A + B$ is open if $A$ (by symmetry) or $B$ is open, e.g. as the sum is a union of homeomorphs of an open set.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps a great deal. The normal union is, I think, what I was intuitively thinking.